# ActiveReport 3.0 (.NET Framework 2.0) will work in .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, .net-4.5, activereports

I have Active Report 3.0 version for .Net Framework 2.0 and it is working fine.

But I want to upgrade my Asp.Net Application to .Net Framework 4.5 will this Active Report 3.0 version work in .Net Framework 4.5?

Thank in advance for Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since AR3 was never tested with .Net Framework 4.5, the application created with AR3 might/might not work with it.

Moreover, designing of AR3 reports would not be supported with .Net Framework 4.5

However, the latest version of AR (AR8) would support 4.5 framework. You may download the same from [here](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ActiveReports/Downloads/).

And the steps for upgrade can be found [here](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR8Help/AR8_HelpOnlineEN/Upgrading%20Reports.html).

Regards,
Mohita